# Different name for ipad application

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval, submission

i have developed an ipad application. now i want to submit the application on apple store. My application name is quite long enough `"*** ***** *****"` which can not be fully seen on ipad screen. but can i have different app name for display like `*** ****` on ipad and Different for apple store submission.

Kindly help.
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Info.plist, look for the key "Bundle display name", that's the name that will show under the icon.

When you submit to the AppStore, they'll let you pick a name. This one will not override that name on the Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `CFBundleDisplayName = "Your name";` in your InfoPlist.strings file. This will enable you to localized the app name.